# The meaning of "in good faith"

Tags: phrase-meaning, legalese

If you act in good faith, you act in a way that you **believe** to be honest, but could it also mean that you act in a way that you **intend** to be honest and fair? Put another way, could e.g., *She acted in good faith* be interpreted not only as 'She believed that what she did was the right thing to do', but also as 'She acted in a decent and fair way'? I have consulted Cambridge dictionary, Merriam-Webster and a bilingual dictionary – according to Merriam-Webster *in good faith* means "in an honest and proper way", which would seem to indicate that both readings are correct, but I'm not entirely sure...

Edit: Ok, I see that my use of *intend* is confusing the matter. What I'm wondering is whether *in good faith* can be used to describe someone's behaviour as such, not only the belief that such behaviour is based on (if that makes things any clearer...). So that *She acted in good faith* could mean either that her actions were based on her belief that what she did was the right thing to do, or that her actions as such were carried out in an honest and decent way.

Comment: compare: to something in bad faith. intention is a separate issue. "The road to hell is paved with good intentions." :)

Comment: If I accept a contract or legal document in good faith, I believe it to be genuine; there is not really any 'intention'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, I know that sense of the expression; what I'm wondering is whether it can also have the other sense described in my OP. I have added an edit now; I don't know whether that makes it any clearer though...

Answer (score 6):

"In good faith" means both: you believe and intend to be honest, fair, etc.

The phrase is usually used when there is a chance that what you are doing will not work out, or in the past tense when it did not work out.

Like, "He sold the car in good faith, believing that it was in good running condition. He was not aware of the serious maintenance problems." Or, "We will make a good faith effort to deliver your package on time. However, we cannot guarantee that we will deliver it by Tuesday, as there may be circumstances beyond our control."

Comment: No, that is not right at all. "I did x in good faith". does not reveal intention per se. If it did, you would not be able to say: I intend to do this in good faith.

Comment: The faith is in what someone *else* does or has done, as [above](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/308891/the-meaning-of-in-good-faith#comment578627_308891).

Comment: @Lambie I've added an edit to my OP now; I see that my use of "intend" only confused the matter... I didn't mean that intention is part of the meaning of "in good faith" as such; I only brought it up to bring out the contrast with belief... Oh, this is hard to explain...

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah, yes – that corresponds to the belief meaning, but can it also refer only to the actions of the person doing something? Lambie's example "I intend to do this in good faith" and Jay's example "We will make a good faith effort..." seem to suggest that it can also have this other meaning?

Comment: Not in my world - it's like bragging about one's own virtue.

Comment: Thank you Jay! The first of your examples, with the car, is the sense I'm sure about, but your second example seems to suggest that it can also be used to describe the way someone acts. I'm a bit confused by the first sentence in your answer though – I would've thought "in good faith" means either that someone's actions are based on the belief about honesty etc, or that someone's actions **are** honest etc not both meanings at the same time?

Comment: @WeatherVane Are you saying that you couldn't say "I intend to do this in good faith", or... Hm... not sure I understand what you mean...

Comment: @Helen I guess that could be its usage in other cultures. I am used to it being used to describe my reaction to other people's actions, not as a way of saying "yea, I am honest and trustworthy."

Comment: @lambie "Good faith" can be past or future. One can say, "Bob did this in good faith" or "Bob will do this in good faith". I'd say that "I intend to do this in good faith" is somewhat redundant. Like saying, "I plan to do this in the future". As opposed to what? Planning to do it in the  past? The fact that people sometimes say that surely does not prove that "plan" does not imply something in the future. We often say redundant things like this. Someone might say, "I intend to act with good intentions".

Comment: @Helen If someone says, "What I say is true", versus, "I believe that what I say is true", the difference is a matter of degree. The first implies certainly, the second admits some doubt. When someone says, "I am acting in good faith", it implies a certain amount of uncertainty. The person claims that what he is doing is, TO THE BEST OF HIS KNOWLEDGE AND ABILITY, honest and true. But the phrase implies there is some doubt.

Comment: @Jay Yes, I completely see how that applies to the first sense; that's the whole essence of a belief: that it involves some uncertainty, right? I'm still wondering whether there is also a **different sense** though, that doesn't involve someone's belief about something, but that just describes something directly, as being honest, decent and proper?

Comment: "good faith effort" and "act in good faith" are different senses of this phrase. The first describes a level of effort, the second is more about intentions and beliefs.

Comment: @Jay I never said it couldn't. I said good faith and intention are not the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

In general "in good faith" is used to convey an absence of malice and an absence of a deliberate act of deception. The expression isn't particularly precise beyond that.

Saying *She acted in good faith* means

- She did not intend to harm anyone with her actions and did not believe that anyone would be harmed by those actions.

and

- She did not intend to deceive anyone through her actions and did not believe that anyone would be deceived through her actions.

Comment: Sometimes the act of good faith can involve innocent belief by the actor, and belief by that actor in the honest intention of another. An example might be when an innocent buyer (a 'purchaser in good faith') purchases property and it turns out that it had been stolen.